Hannover: "ich war" vs. "ich bin gewesen"
Seit meinem Umzug nach Deutschland, genauer gesagt nach Hannover, beobachte ich die Nuancen der deutschen Sprache genau. Eine davon ist die Verwendung von "ich/er war" und "ich bin/er ist gewesen", die den allgemeinen Regeln für die Verwendung des Präteritums und des Perfekts scheinbar nicht unterliegt. Während ich weiß, dass "ich war" im Hochdeutschen standardmäßig gelehrt wird, habe ich bemerkt, dass "ich bin gewesen" in der Stadt auch gebraucht wird.
Zwei lokale Freunde haben mir das Folgende gesagt:

Unterschiede im Zeitrahmen: "Ich war" scheine für jüngere Ereignisse verwendet zu werden, während "ich bin gewesen" oft für Dinge verwendet werde, die länger zurückliegen.
Kontextuelle Nutzung: "Ich bin gewesen" werde häufiger verwendet, wenn man über Personen spricht, und weniger über Orte. Zum Beispiel klinge "Ich bin gestern bei Peter gewesen" natürlich, während "Ich bin gestern am Maschsee gewesen" unpassend wirke.
Formalität: In der Alltagssprache sei "ich/er war" häufiger, während "ich bin/er ist gewesen" formeller erscheine. Das hat mich überrascht, weil ich weiß, dass das Präteritum typischerweise formeller ist und das Perfekt für den alltäglichen Gebrauch gedacht ist. Interessanterweise habe ich die Perfektform fast immer in informellen Gesprächen gehört und kaum in formellen Kontexten.

Für diejenigen, die Hannover oder allgemein Niedersachsen kennen (besonders wenn ihr dort lebt oder gelebt habt), wie würdet ihr die Unterschiede in der Verwendung dieser beiden Formen beschreiben? Stimmt ihr den oben genannten Beobachtungen zu? Ich möchte die Perfektform in meine Sprache einbauen, möchte aber sicherstellen, dass es sich natürlich anhört.

Ich komme aus Ostfalen.
Bei einigen Verben das Präteritum anstatt des Perfekts zu verwenden ist einfach eine norddeutsche Abkürzung. Du kannst Ich war bei Peter. oder Ich bin bei Peter gewesen. sagen, es bedeutet dasselbe und es gibt auch keine Regel dafür, wann man was sagt. Und genauso gilt das auch für Ich war am Maschsee. oder Ich bin am Maschsee gewesen.
Allerdings wird das Präteritum im Standarddeutschen ja außerdem für die Gegenwart innerhalb einer Erzählung verwendet, und im gesprochenen Wort kann man so verdeutlichen, dass dieser Teil den größeren Kontext darstellt, in den man den Zuhörer hineinversetzen will. Also z.B.

Ich war gerade bei Peter, und da hat doch glatt wieder mein Chef angerufen.

Hier finden beide Handlungen gleichzeitig in der Vergangenheit statt. Der erste Teil bildet allerdings die Rahmenhandlung (die Erzählung) innerhalb der dann der zweite Teil stattfindet.

Danke! Ja, das deutsche Präteritum setzt meist ein größeres Bild voraus als das Perfekt, soweit ich sehe. Eine andere Person hat dazu gesagt, dass für sie der Satz über den See mit der Perfektform umständlich klingen würde, weil man normalerweise den Vorgang betonen möchte und nicht die Tatsache des Seebesuchs, wenn man darüber redet (und wenn man im Satz über Peter einfach sagen möchte, dass er ihn gesehen hat, sei das nicht der Fall und beides wäre möglich).

Es ist denke ich am besten, das Präteritum ganz generell als Erzählzeit anzusehen anstatt als Vergangenheit. Die meisten Erzählungen spielen in der Vergangenheit der Realität, das stimmt. Aber das muss nicht so sein. Der Zweck des Präteritums ist es, den Zuhörer in eine andere Situation hineinzuversetzen.

Das ist typische Sprach"okonomie. "Ich war" ist kurz und vermeidet, insbesondere dann, wenn man weitere Unterschiede und Erkl"arungen f"ur den Ort, in dem man gewesen ist, noch nachschieben muss, dass man am Ende des Satzes nicht mehr weiss, ob man mit "Ich war" oder "ich bin..." den Satz angefangen hat. Wer so etwas niederschreibt, kann den Satz mehrfalls korrekturlesen; in der gesprochenen Rede gibt es solche a-posteriori Verbesserungen nicht.
Des weiteren gilt so etwas "ahnliches wie im Englischen: das Pr"ateritum ist f"ur die abgeschlossenen Sachen. Das  Perfekt k"undigt an, dass der Sprecher noch etwas genaueres zu dem Platz (an dem er gewesen ist..) sagen wird.

Zunächst ein paar Grundlagen: es gibt drei verschiedene Zeitformen im Deutschen, die mit Vergangenem zu tun haben: Präteritum ("Mitvergangenheit", manchmal auch fälschlich "Imperfekt"), Perfekt ("Vergangenheit") und Plusquamperfekt ("Vorvergangenheit").
Während das Präteritum eine eigene Form hat (Ablaut bei starken Verben, das Suffix "-t-" bei schwachen Verben) werden die beiden anderen mit dem Partizip Perfekt gebildet. Das Perfekt mit der Präsensform des jeweiligen Hilfszeitworts ("haben" oder "sein") und dem Partizip, das Plusquamperfekt mit dem Präteritum des Hilfszeitworts und dem Partizip:

Ich war -> Präteritum
ich bin gewesen -> Perfekt
ich war gewesen -> Plusquamperfekt

Falls es interessiert, kann ich näher ausführen, wie diese Zeiten entstanden sind, zunächst aber, wie sie heute verwendet werden:
Sowohl das Präteritum wie auch das Perfekt beschreiben Vergangenes. Dabei wird im Norden des deutschen Sprachraums in der gesprochenen Sprache hauptsächlich das Präteritum verwendet, nach Süden zunehmend das Perfekt. Das hat historische Gründe, die noch aus dem Alt- und Mittelhochdeutschen herrühren und hängt mit dem Unterschied zwischen Hoch-, Mittel- und Niederdeutsch zusammen. Hannover liegt an der Grenze des (ehemaligen) mitteldeutschen und niederdeutschen Sprachgebiets (mehr über diese Gebiete kann man bei Wikipedia erfahren, wenn man nach Benrather Linie sucht) und deshalb trifft man dort vermutlich auch beide Varianten.
In der Schriftsprache wird das Präteritum als Erzählzeit verwendet: Romane, Märchen, Geschichten und dergleichen sind üblicherweise im Präteritum verfaßt und da vertritt das Präteritum die Stelle des Präsens. Das, was in einem Roman "jetzt" passiert, steht im Präteritum.
Das Plusquamperfekt dient dazu, Vorzeitigkeit auszudrücken: wenn von einem Ereignis A, das seinerseits in der Vergangenheit liegt, ausgehend ein anderes Ereignis B beschrieben werden soll, das noch vor A stattfand, dann kann man das Plusquamperfekt verwenden:

Ich ging, nachdem ich die Tür zugeschlagen hatte.

Soll hingegen eine solche Vorzeitigkeit für ein Ereignis im Präsens beschrieben werden, so wird das Perfekt verwendet:

Ich gehe, nachdem ich die Tür zugeschlagen habe.


Danke, aber das wusste ich alles schon, außer über die Benrather Linie. Meine Frage bezieht sich speziell auf den regionalen Unterschied zwischen dem Präteritum und dem Perfekt von "sein". Wenn ich mehr über das allgemeine Verhältnis zwischen diesen beiden Zeitformen lernen möchte, würde ich die Frage ganz anders formulieren.

„Dabei wird im Norden des deutschen Sprachraums in der gesprochenen Sprache hauptsächlich das Präteritum verwendet“ — Das stimmt nicht. Es wird auch im Norden fast immer das Perfekt verwendet, nur bei den Hilfsverben, den Modalverben und einigen wenigen anderen Verben eben nicht, oder nicht immer.
